# How to configure StrongSwan IKEv2 VPN with PSK (pre-shared key)?

Tags: vpn, strongswan

I'm looking for a configuration instructions for IKEv2 VPN that uses `pre-shared keys` instead of `certs` (those are different methods for tunnel encryption I'd assume?).

I've followed [this wonderful tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-16-04) to get IKEv2 VPN working (with `certificate`) and it works.

My question is what needs to be changed so that it would use `PSK` instead? I'd assume changes in `/etc/ipsec.secrets` and `/etc/ipsec.conf` are to be made.

My current `ipsec.conf` looks like this:

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@server_name_or_ip
    leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/vpn-server-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

---

**UPD:** Based on my tinkering and @ChandanK answer, I've made two scripts to deploy a StrongSwan VPN server on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install here: https://github.com/truemetal/ikev2_vpn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you want to setup your right side with psk. 
This is fairly easy.

`1. remove eap_identity and rightsendcert fields.
 2. set rightauth=secret`

Now edit /etc/ipsec.secrets file:

`1. remove "your_username %any% : EAP "your_password"" line. 
 2. add ": PSK <your_password>"`

Then reread the secrets and restart the service.

`$sudo ipsec rereadsecrets
 $sudo ipsec reload
 $sudo ipsec restart`

All set. Follow "Connecting from iOS" and create a new ikev2 vpn connection. In authentication settings select none and put the shared secret key. Hopefully you connect.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments, configuration changes required to switch to pre-shared key authentication:

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@server_name_or_ip
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
    authby=secret
```

Remove the following line from ipsec.secrets:

`server_name_or_ip : RSA "/etc/ipsec.d/private/vpn-server-key.pem`

Then reread the secrets and restart the service.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. So `left` is VPN server, and `right` are iOS clients. I'd probably prefer to keep `username/password pair` and use `PSK` instead of `cert`. I do have to use either `cert` or `PSK`, correct?

Comment: Anything should be added to `ipsec.conf` for PSK? What about `leftcert` and `leftsendcert` fields, are those to be removed?

Comment: leftcert and leftsendcert is for server verification with client. In your client side ipsec.conf (on ubuntu client for example) you should have "rightauth=pubkey". Obviously you have to copy server-root-ca.pem at desired location. If your concern is this should also be psk, then remove these two lines and add leftauth=secret. Also you need to change the ipsec.secrets file too to incorporate this change and be careful with ids. Check out this: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Ipsecsecrets

Comment: I need to use `psk` instead of `.pem cert`. Could you please extend your answer with the correct `ipsec.conf` contents? I'll deploy a VPS and test that configuration right if you do that.

Comment: * right away, if you do that

Comment: For a simple setup: you can remove `leftcert` and `leftsendcert` fields. Also remove `rightauth=secret` and add `authby=secret`. This will take care both {left|rightauth=psk}. Also remove `server_name_or_ip : RSA "/etc/ipsec.d/private/vpn-server-key.pem"` from ipsec.secrets file. You don't need this. Finally `sudo ipsec rereadsecrets|reload|restart`. All set, connect from client.

Comment: I've adjusted `ipsec.conf` according to your comments above. Please confirm if that looks right: https://pastebin.com/Y3mDsBqQ

Comment: Looks good. Add `rightsubnet=10.10.10.0/24`.

Comment: Did you got this working?

Comment: I've just checked and It did work. Thank you. Adding right subnet tuned out to be not necessary - worked without that. Please add contents of the `ipsec.conf` from last `pastebin` for others to see and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @ChandanK Is this the way to setup your VPN when you need a shared secret? (if yes, what will be the shared secret in the case above?)

Comment: @ChandanK  Is it PSK <your_password>? + do I need to follow any of the steps about certificates (in this tutorial)

Comment: @DenCowboy PSK stands for "pre shared key"; if you're looking forward that, you should not really need certificates

Comment: @DannieP thanks, tonight I'll try the setup. But what is the "shared secret". For example on google cloud I need to provide a shared secret when I create a tunnel: https://www.cloudassessments.com/blog/extend-your-network-to-google-cloud-using-cloud-vpn/

Comment: @DenCowboy I think you can try the PSK as shared secret. It works here in macOS settings: https://www.evernote.com/l/AYVKjgmPfIVIGZ4csEQjNoSwIgy0R43Q79kB/image.png

Comment: Thanks! So that's the <your_password> in the answer of ChandanK?

Comment: @DenCowboy yes, right. I've found some time and posted my scripts on github, check it out - maybe you'll find it useful: https://github.com/truemetal/ikev2_vpn

Comment: It was very useful. I'm able to connect to my VPN, the only 'issue' remaining is that I loose my internet connection when I'm connected. I'm checking the strongswan forums now.

Comment: @DenCowboy internet drops right after you run the script and connect to vpn? It definitely worked for me (the PSK way), I connected from macos.

Comment: @DenCowboy I've found issues like that happen when you screw up something in iptables. That's actually the reason I made those scripts - I would just screw something up when copying the commands by hand.

Comment: @DenCowboy I've checked `ikev2-deploy-certs.sh` and it works. Anyways since several people asked questions on this script, I've updated the repo with a demo video on deployment and connection using that script. It's on the front page (readme) now. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Based on my tinkering and @ChandanK answer, I've made two scripts to deploy a StrongSwan VPN server on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install here: https://github.com/truemetal/ikev2_vpn

Comment: Hi I follow your thread and got this error `unable to resolve %any, initiate aborted`, any idea?

Comment: Hey @23r23f23q, I'm not sure what the problem could be, but you might want to check out the deployment demo video on the GitHub repo page - it worked in February. Cheers